# Create a login view using UIAlertView

Tags: ios, authentication, uialertview, xcode4.5

I am trying to create a login for users to enter their username and password.  I am using Xcode 4.5.  Here is my code for the .h file:

```
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
    #import "AccountViewController.m"

    @interface AccountViewController : UIViewController {


    }


    - (IBAction) alert: (id)sender;

    @end
```

Here is my code for the .m file:

```
    #import "AccountViewController.h"



    @implementation AccountViewController


    - (IBAction)alert:(id)sender
    {
    UIAlertView *alert =[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Log In" message:@"Please enter      your    Username and Password" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Log In"         otherButtonTitles:@"Cancel", nil];

    [alert addTextFieldWithValue:@"" label:@"Username"];
    [alert addTextFieldWithValue:@"" label:@"Password"];

    UITextField *tf = [alert textFieldAtIndex:0];
    tf.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;
    tf.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeAlphabet;
    tf.keyboardAppearance = UIKeyboardAppearanceAlert;
    tf.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeWords;
    tf.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;

    tf = [alert textFieldAtIndex:1];
    tf.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;
    tf.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeURL;
    tf.keyboardAppearance = UIKeyboardAppearanceAlert;
    tf.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeWords;
    tf.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;

    [alert show];


    }

    - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
    }


    - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning]; // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview
    // Release anything that's not essential, such as cached data
    }


    - (void)dealloc {

    }



    @end
```

The error is occurs here in the .m file for each of the following lines of code:

```
    [alert addTextFieldWithValue:@"" label:@"Username"];
    [alert addTextFieldWithValue:@"" label:@"Password"];
```

Error is : No visible @interface for 'UIAlertView' declares the selector 'addTextFieldWithValue:label:'

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What is `addTextFieldWithValue` doing here? There is no such method listed under `UIAlertView`.

Also, if you going to deal with tap events on the buttons of the alert, please include the `UIAlertViewDelegate` to your class.